# Issue status (specified, coded, tested, ...) and percentage

Tags: project-management, redmine

After struggling a bit to install it on a shared hosting, I finally discovered the power of Redmine. I must say I'm pretty impressed. However I'm a beginner, and stumbling into the manual and the forums didn't help much for what I'm trying to do, so I ask here. Please forgive me if it's already addressed somewhere.

We are doing a software development project, and we are trying to get organized. At the moment, we entered all the developement tasks as features into Redmine. However we would like to enforce that, for a task to be completed, it must have been 
- specified
- coded
- tested
- some other project specific stuff not relevant here

I can't use issue statuses, because that would impose a particular order (like testing after coding, BUT sometimes, we want to be able to write the test before the code, and sometimes not)

I don't really know how to achieve that :-(

What I tried so far is :

- for every task, create a subtask, for coding, testing, and so on ... It works well but it's very tedious, and it makes the number of issues a bit overwhelming
- use custom boolean fields. It's ok but :

  -I can't make a search filter like "find the tasks which are NOT

  -I can't setup the completion percentage to depend on the subtasks (e.g : prevent someone from marking a task as 100% completed if it hasn't been tested)
  I'd like to get some insights from experienced Redmine users, about how to achieve this. I must admit I'm a beginner in both Redmine and project management, so I'm really trying hard to find the best way to deal with that.

Any help appreciated
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand I think you should still consider the status field. In Redmine you can define what status changes are permitted (defining allowed destinations for a specific status).

For example you could define the following statuses

- New
- Specified
- Coded
- Tested
- Deployed
- Closed

From "New" you would define that a specific role can change only to "Specified" (perhaps enforcing not to implement without specifying). From "Specified" you could allow changes to "Coded" and "Tested". From "coded" or "tested" to "deployed". And only from deployed to closed.

You could also define a specific workflow for a role and a specific kind of issue (what Redmine calls tracker), but define a different workflow for a different tracker.

It's very powerful, but you'll have to tailor it to your specific needs.

To access the workflows you need to go to the Admin page.

HTH-

Comment: Sounds good, but then you have to enforce specific order : specified, THEN coded THEN tested, and so on

Comment: When you define the initial status (Default in Redmine jargon), and the end status (Closed for Redmine), and you define the transitions, you can choose to enforce a specific order or a somewhat more open order. If you need a strict order, for a status you specify one and only one available transition. If you need a flexible order, you define a workflow where for a specific status there should be more than one available transitions (destination statuses). Take a look at Workflow. It's really powerful.